# wpf datagrid bound to xml data cannot autogenerate columns?

Tags: wpf, xml, data-binding, datagrid

I was wondering why I cannot make my wpf datagrid autogenerate the columns. The propery AutogerenateColumns is set to true. Maybe it has to do with the fact that I don't bind the itemssource to a class but to a XElement. If there maybe a limitation? I could not find any info about this. Thanks

This is the xaml:

```
    <DataGrid
        x:Name="grid"
        Grid.Row="3"
        Grid.Column="2"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Elements[person]}"
        DataContext="{Binding Path=ResourceFileGroupMerged}"
        AutoGenerateColumns="True">
    </DataGrid>
```

In the ViewModel:

```
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
               ResourceFileGroupMerged = XElement.Load(@"c:\test.xml");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to manually add columns, as DataGrid would use properties of XmlElement (such as NodeType, OwnerDocument, etc.) as autogenerated columns. You should use `XPath` instead of `Path` in your binding:

```
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=Elements/person}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataContext="{Binding Path=ResourceFileGroupMerged}" >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding XPath=@prop1}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding XPath=@prop2}" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

Where `@prop1` and `@prop2` are attributes of your `person` XmlElement.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know that it works with AutogeneratedColumns=False. My question is why (and if) it does not work with AutogeneratedColumn = True. My problem is that I don't know in advance how many columns there are so I cannot explicitly add columns in xaml.

Comment: @user1472131 Probably it's because by default, the binding looks for public properties in an object, as I mentioned before. I'm afraid you have to use code-behind to add columns at runtime.